# imageMagick : replace image's color as tintColor

Tags: macos, colors, imagemagick

in iOS, there is a tintColor property in View. Then use it to replace image's color, rendering image as template.

like this

[image: 00]

The color is perfect.

While I use imagemagick http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_basics/#replace,

```
convert  -fuzz 40%     0.png -fill "#FE003E" -opaque "#3B7EF2"  1.png
```

[image: 333]

There are some blue points.

Bigger of it:

[image: 666]

Here is the raw image:

[image: 2222]

How to do it more accurate with imagemagick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here one simple way to do it in ImageMagick.

Your image has all the antialiasing in the alpha channel and the underlying image is mostly blue with some extraneous white outside the arrow and lines. So all we need to do is make the underlying image completely red without affecting the alpha channel.

Arrow Image:

[image]

```
convert arrow.png -fill red -colorize 100 result.png
```

[image]